# How to test JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder with Junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-batch

I'm creating a spring-batch application, and I'm having trouble creating a unit test class with junit that tests my reader that uses **JdbcPaginItemReaderBuilder**.

Reader Code:

```
@Configuration
public class RelatorioReader {

    @Bean("relatorioreader")
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<Relatorio> relatorioItemReader(
        @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
        @Value("#{jobParameters[dateParam]}") String dateParam) {

        return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<Relatorio>()
                    .name("relatorioDiario")
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .selectClause("SELET * ")
                    .fromClause("FROM myTable ")
                    .whereClause(" WHERE date = :dateParam")
                    .parameterValues(Collections.singletonMap("dateParam", dateParam))
                    .sortKeys(Collections.singletonMap("ID", Order.ASCENDING))
                    .rowMapper(new RelatorioMapper())
                    .build();
    }
}
```

Junit Code

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class RelatorioReaderTest {

    @InjectMocks
    RelatorioReader reader;

    @Mock
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Test
    public void test_itemReader() {
        ItemReader<Relatorio> itemReader = reader.relatorioItemReader(dataSource, "2023-02-16");

        assertNotNull(itemReader);
    }
}
```

Exception when running Junit:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to determine PagingQueryProvider type
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder.determineQueryProvider(JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder.java:383)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder.build(JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder.java:335)
    at com.erico.relatorio.item.reader.RelatorioReader.relatorioItemReader(RelatorioReader.java:34)
    at com.erico.relatorio.item.reader.RelatorioReaderTest.test_itemReader(RelatorioReaderTest.java:27)
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): dataSource
    at ...
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): dataSource
    at ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do not specify a paging query provider, the builder will try to determine a suitable one from the meta-data of your data source. Since you are using a mocked database, you need to mock the call to `getConnection()`.  Otherwise, you have to use a stub database for tests (like an embedded H2 or HSQL).

If you know what datasource you will be using, the best way is to specify its paging query provider implementation in your builder. Here is an example if you use H2:

```
@Configuration
public class RelatorioReader {

    @Bean("relatorioreader")
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<Relatorio> relatorioItemReader(
        @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
        @Value("#{jobParameters[dateParam]}") String dateParam) {

        return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<Relatorio>()
                    .name("relatorioDiario")
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .selectClause("SELET * ")
                    .fromClause("FROM myTable ")
                    .whereClause(" WHERE date = :dateParam")
                    .parameterValues(Collections.singletonMap("dateParam", dateParam))
                    .sortKeys(Collections.singletonMap("ID", Order.ASCENDING))
                    .rowMapper(new RelatorioMapper())
                    .queryProvider(new H2PagingQueryProvider())
                    .build();
    }
}
```